# Would it be possible to add dual screen support on Android 11 for Capacitorjs?

Tags: android, capacitor

I'm trying to figure out how to use DisplayManager on Android 11 into Capacitorjs to implement multi screen display.

Does anyone knows how the Main capacitor activity is created so I can reproduce it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting an answer since I managed to do it:

Simply make a new activity with a Web browser in it.
If you need communication between native & the web browser, just use the basic Javascript bridge.